# Angular, function is undefined when passed to a class in model, but works if called directly

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a class that has a function that would start a self calling loop every 5 seconds that would check a certain server settings using http.request library and, when the setting matches the one that is defined in the calling arguments, it would emit a signal and stop calling itself. (I haven't actually gotten into writing the job itself, just to the point of trying to get the setup work).

The problem is that I have a method for calling the server which works if directly called from the component, but it gives the following error when the function in the model tries to use it:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')
```

This is the basic logic that I'm using:

The component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from '../../server.service';
import { SafePipe } from '../../_helpers/safe.pipe';
import { SharedVariables } from '../../_services/shared-variables.service';
import { ServerSettingValueObserver } from '../../_models/valueObservers.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-analytics',
  templateUrl: './analytics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analytics.component.css']
})
export class AnalyticsComponent implements OnInit {
  analyticsUrl;
  iframeStatus = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private server: ServerService, private sharedVariables: SharedVariables, private safe: SafePipe) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedVariables.getAnalyticsUrl().subscribe((value) => {
      this.analyticsUrl = value;
    });
    var value_observer = new ServerSettingValueObserver("iframeEnabled", true, this.iframeStatus);
    value_observer.startJob(this.server.getServerSettings);
  }

  changeMatomoStatus() {
    this.server.changeMatomoStatus().then((res) => {
      console.log("changed");
    });
  }
}
```

This is the relevant service that is being passed to the function in the class:

```
  getServerSettings() {
    return this.request('GET', '/api/settings/server');
  }
```

And this is the model:

```
export class ServerSettingValueObserver{
  constructor(
    public value: string,
    public state: boolean,
    public signal: any,
  ){ }

  public startJob(job: any): void{
    console.log('job',job)
    job().then((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the output of the console.log:

```
job ƒ getServerSettings(){return this.request("GET","/api/settings/server")}
```

I think that should mean that the object that is passed to the function should be a function, but why do I get the error in this case?

Just to test things out I tried directly calling the function in the service and it worked without problem.

For this test I substituted:

```
var value_observer = new ServerSettingValueObserver("iframeEnabled", true, this.iframeStatus);
value_observer.startJob(this.server.getServerSettings);
```

With:

```
this.server.getServerSettings().then((response: any) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: need stackblitz example to work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line:

```
    value_observer.startJob(this.server.getServerSettings)
```

To this:

```
    value_observer.startJob(() => this.server.getServerSettings())
```

Or this:

```
     value_observer.startJob(this.server.getServerSettings.bind(this.server))
```

You're getting an error because when you pass the function as an argument this way, it loses the `this` context, so `this` will be indeed undefined. To keep the correct value for `this`, you have to pass an arrow function (first example) or bind the value of `this` manually (second example).